# Let `PlotLabel` use data set names in a list of plots

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

In the code below, how to make `PlotLabel` automatically show the name of the data sets (i.e., aa, bb, cc)?

```
aa = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
bb = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
cc = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
Table[MatrixPlot[data, PlotLabel -> ?? ],{data,{aa,bb,cc}}]
```

Comment: `Row[MapThread[
  MatrixPlot[#1, PlotLabel -> #2] &, {{aa, bb, cc}, {"aa", "bb", 
    "cc"}}]]` ?

Comment: @Xminer Thanks, but this does not extract the names automatically.

Comment: `Column[MatrixPlot[ToExpression@#,
    PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {"aa", "bb", "cc"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[MatrixPlot[First @ data, PlotLabel -> data],
    {data, Defer /@ Unevaluated[{aa, bb, cc}]}]
```

[image]

```
Table[MatrixPlot[ReleaseHold @ data, PlotLabel -> data], 
     {data, HoldForm /@ Unevaluated[{aa, bb, cc}]}]
```

> same picture